# Followers in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

When I leave my follower somewhere and can't find them, how do I get them back? And will they have the amor and weapons I gave them?

Answer (score -1):

you Haft to wait if that doesn't work wait where you left the follower if that doesn't work he's glitches and yes also you can glitch his/her carry wait by marking her pick it up arm or by using command so she can carry billions of armor you welcome

Comment: Please, try to use punctuation in your answer.